# How to hide charts in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm just trying to hide or group lines in my spreadsheet but in these lines there is a chart (which I'd also like to be hidden/grouped).

For some reason when doing so, the chart stays put (without data). How can I make it "hideable"?

Comment: The chart itself cannot be hidden, but you can move it to its own sheet, or filter out the chart data. Would any of these workarounds work for you?

Comment: That's quite a useless workaround when you have more than a couple charts to work on